Derivative of $f \in BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ with $f =0$ a.e.
Suppose I have $f \in BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and some open set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $f =  0$ a.e. on $K$. Then is it true that $\partial_{x}f$ must necessarily be a measure (and not $L^p$) if $f$ is not identically $0$ everywhere that it is defined?
Intuitively, it seems like the result should be true since there should be a jump discontinuity. For example if $K = (-1,1)$ you could have $f = \mathbb{1}_{\{x=0\}}$ and so $f = 0$ a.e. and $\partial_{x}f = \delta_{\{x=0\}}$. I find it hard to believe there could be an example where $f = 0$ a.e. but $\partial_{x}f$ is not a measure, but I am not sure how to prove it.
I tried to argue as follows. Let $E \subset K = (-1,1)$ be such that $|E| = 0$ and $f = 0$ a.e. on $E$. Then let $y \in E$ be a point where $f$ is defined and such that $f(y) \ne 0$. Then one idea would be to show that $lim_{x \to y^{-}} f(x) \ne lim_{x \to y^{+}} f(x)$. But because $f$ is a Lebesgue function, I don't think this pointwise evaluation within the limit makes sense so I got stuck here.
I would appreciate any help.

If by $\delta_xf$ you mean the distribution derivative of $f$, then $\delta_xf$ is a signed Radon measure because $f\in BV_{\rm loc}(\Bbb R)$.
If also $f=0$ a.e. on some open $K\subset\Bbb R$, then the associated distribution $\phi\mapsto\int \phi\cdot f,dx$ vanishes on smooth functions $\phi$ supported in $K$, so $\delta_xf$ vanishes in $K$ as well.

@JohnDawkins I agree with what you have written, that $f=0$ in $\mathcal{D}'$ and thus $\partial_{x}f = 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'$. But then I cannot see why my counterexample of $f = \mathbf{1}{{x=0}}$ is incorrect? I calculated that $\partial{x}f = \delta_{x=0}$ which is not the $0$ distribution, while of course $f=0$ a.e.

Your example $f$, as a distribution, is $0$.

@JohnDawkins Yes... oops! If you want to write what you commented as an answer I will accept it :)

If by $\delta_xf$ you mean the distribution derivative of $f$, then $\delta_xf$ is a signed Radon measure because $f\in BV_{\rm loc}(\Bbb R)$. If also $f=0$ a.e. on some open $K\subset \Bbb R$, then the associated distribution $\phi\mapsto\int \phi\cdot f\,dx$ vanishes on smooth functions $\phi$ supported in $K$, so $\delta_xf$ vanishes in $K$ as well.
